# Табулирования функции и вывод результатов в таблице

Tags: c++

Составить программу вычисления функции с использованием оператора цикла с предусловием. Переменная х меняется с шагом h на заданном промежутке [a, b].

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите найти ошибку

```
#include<cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  double z, x, xn, xk, h;
  cin >> xn >> xk >> h;
  while (x <= xk)
    if (xn <= x < 0) {
      z = cos(x) * sin(x) / 2;
    }
  if (0 <= x <= 2 * xk / 3) {
    z = pow(sin(x + 1), 2);
  }
  if (2 * xk / 3 < x <= xk) {
    z = pow(cos(x - 1), 2);
    printf("%6.2f5s %9.3f", x, z);
  }
  x = x + h;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Мэри, вы ли это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибки:

1. Начальное значение переменной `x` не указано
2. цикл `while` содержит вычисление только одной функции. Остальные две и увеличение `x` происходит за циклом.

Вот исправленный вариант

```c++
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  double z, x, xn, xk, h;
  cin >> xn >> xk >> h;
  x = xn;
  while (x <= xk) {
    if (x < 0)
      z = cos(x) * sin(x) / 2;
    else if (x <= 2 * xk / 3)
      z = pow(sin(x + 1), 2);
    else
      z = pow(cos(x - 1), 2);
    printf("%6.2f %9.3f\n", x, z);
    x += h;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое, но всё равно http://ideone.com/01ubdX

Comment: @Stell исправил. Не хватало инклуда

Comment: Люди, вы что??!! `xn <= x < 0` - это что такое?! Это же нонсенс! Оно же сравнивается как `(xn <= x) < 0`, так что это **всегда** `false`. Прочие сравнения в том же духе... Как говорится - идите учите матчасть...

Comment: @Harry Вы абсолютно правы. Я просто скопировал код автора особо не присматриваясь. Сейчас исправил

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Если вы еще уберете непонятные `5s` из `printf` и добавите туда `\n` - будет совсем здорово... Еще - после инициализации `x = xn;` **всегда** `x >= xn`, так что это условие можно выбрасывать. Нет смысла проверять все три ветви - лучше ставить во второй и третьей - `else if` и `else`...

Comment: @Harry Изначально не хотелось сильно курочить код автора. Там и в `if` половина условий лишних

Answer (score 2):

Как я понимаю, будет еще 33 экземпляра этого же вопроса...
Ладно, дожали. Красоту в выводе наведите сами...

```
const double Pi = 3.1415926;
const double h  = Pi/6.0;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(double x = -Pi; x < Pi + h/2; x += h)
    {
        double z = (x < 0.0)     ? cos(x)*sin(x)/2.0 :
                   (x <= 2*Pi/3) ? sin(x+1)*sin(x+1) :
                                   cos(x-1)*cos(x-1);
        cout << " x = " << x << "   z = " << z << endl;

    }
}
```